# Putting Incremental values in array

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following code

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
{
echo $i . "<br>";
}
?>
```

which Results 1 2 3 4

I have another code which have a variable $number = 1 and coding is as follows

```
if ($number = $i) 
{ 
echo "Message" ;
}
```

MY issue is i need to check the variable $number(1) is available in the list of values displayed by variable $i.

Can anybody find a solution for that? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this this will put your incremental values in array and after that you can validate with any number

```
 $inc=array();
 for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
  {
   array_push($inc,$i);
  }
 $number=1;
if(in_array($number, $inc))
 {
   echo "your Message" ;
 }
```

Comment: Exactly Mr Ranjan, If this code is developed by yourself, you are an expert programmer in PHP, Your solution is the best one, Only you have 156 reputation ? :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `==` ([comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)) instead of `=` to compare two values within an if statement, as follows:

```
if ($number == $i) 
{ 
   echo "Message" ;
}
```

However, assuming that it's just a typo, here is my suggestion:

You can store the numbers to be printed in an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) first.

```
$i = array(1,2,3,4);
foreach($i as $num)
{
   echo $num."<br/>" ;
}
```

Then, you can use the [in_array() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) of php to check if `$number` is present in any of the numbers printed above.

```
if(in_array($number, $i))
{
   echo "Message" ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Kevin , yes assignment is a typo in my program. Your answer is also nice in my first view , but i am not tried, but i would like to recommend to go with automatic generation of array according to the result NOT $i = array(1,2,3,4); FYI look at my selected answer..

Comment: @t0m you're welcome! and no problem at all. You select which is the best for you :)

Comment: Well , I am highly appreciated about your answer and spending little time for me :)

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assigment operator, to compare you have to use `==`

```
if ($number == 1) {
  //...
}
```

Furthermore there are situatons where using

```
if ($number = $value) {
  //...
}
```

is of use. this code would assign $value to $number and 'return' its value, therefore `if ($number = 1) echo "hi";` will echo "hi" - while `if ($number = 0) echo "hi"; will output nothing. A assign like the above is quite useless, it is mostly used when you call a function, you want to restore its return value and compare it in the same step like

```
if ($number = getValue()) {
  //$number is set to getValue() and is not 0, null or false
}
```